# Community reward for correct and unaccepted answers?

Tags: discussion, voting, etiquette, unaccepted-answer

It is frustrating to witness something like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74308404/13629335). Someone invested time and effort into someone else problem, and it seems too much to ask for a button click. I know [life isn't fair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202652/life-isnt-fair).

And the question is not worth putting a bounty on, and the answer will likely not be helpful to others. But still, this user may have spent an hour or so to solve this question, and a single upvote is not enough, in my opinion.

I asked myself if more members feel this way and if it would be reasonable to open up a chat where we share such cases and show them some value for their time and effort by the community.

How do you all think about this?

Comment: Well, a bounty would be to reward the answer. Unless the question needs closing and/or deleting, placing a bounty to reward an existing answer is valid.

Comment: @BSMP I initially voted to close this question. However someone took the time and effort to reconstruct the issue and searched for an answer. Not that the answer itself would be impressive but the willingness to help the OP is what I thought should be rewarded.

Comment: Related: [Should Stack Exchange in general be awarding "A"s for Effort?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210840/289691) from 2013

Comment: "_open up a chat_", I strongly disagree on that point and any other suggestions of a community of some sort to "reward" answers, such a community would very much be like a voting ring where people vote together as a group on posts.

Comment: Note that if "the answer will likely not be helpful to others", then it's not such a great answer, given that Stack Overflow isn't a help desk, but is instead trying to build a collection of Q/A that _is_ helpful to "others".

Comment: Time invested is not a criteria for quality. Quality is a criteria for quality. Usefulness is a criteria for quality. So far the answer you linked to has existed for half a day and it got one upvote. One. So far the usefulness is not really showing itself. A bit presumptuous to start talking about what is fair and what isn't. Not that it really matters, Stack Overflow simply does not work that way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the harsh reality of a Q&A site.  Someone asked a question.  Someone got an answer.

Normally you're taught to say "thanks" after someone does that but it's not mandated anywhere that you actually *do* the things that we consider an act of thanks.

You can pour your heart and soul into an answer and get nothing.  You can offer a one-liner response and get accolades.  As you said, life isn't fair.

What can you do?  Not a whole lot.  If you personally think that answer is good, then upvoting it would be the only practical action you could take.

Comment: Don't you think it would be a good idea to have a chat? Cause at the very moment I have read  *the harsh reality* it popped in my mind that probably a lot of users would join to promote their own answers and may even fake accounts to manipulate the system. Now I think it is a bad idea, thanks for your response to take me back into reality. :D

Comment: No.  I have a day job and hobbies after 5PM.  But more to the point, I think there's a bit of a misconception or blending of expectations between an answerer and the actual goal of the site.  Despite the CEO's insistence of getting more people to "sign up", the reality is that people that use the site have well-defined objectives, and "being social" isn't very high on that list.  Providing an answer to a question as an SME can be cathartic and help one refine that ability - I certainly felt that when I started here almost 12 years ago.

Comment: In effect, users can come here and promote their answers, and they *do* that.  If the rest of us don't know or don't care enough to agree with that sentiment, then...that's really where things stop.  Not everyone's answer is sterling, after all.  But more to the point, not every *question* is all that interesting to motivate an answer more interesting than, "here, pull a few levers."

Comment: So you're not going to get a lot of good purchase on having a chat with anyone who feels like their contributions are being undervalued on the site.  They're valued at exactly what the community values them to be.  It can be frustrating to put a lot of effort into something to not get rewarded, that's fair, but if you keep the original motivations in mind - someone asked a question, I answered it - then that at least provides context to the frustration.

Answer (score -3):

There really is no need to reward spending effort on something that does not help the site at all ("the question is not worth to put a bounty on and the answer will likely not helpful to others.")

From the site's point of view the user should be punished for spending their time on a question that makes it harder to find useful answers and waste time of future visitors on trying to see if question they landed on via search is what they are looking for.

From the answerer point of view they already got their reward of gaining some extra knowledge and getting fluffy feeling of helping someone.

Comment: I personally don't like that nihilistic point you made, though it is a valid one.